# How can i change Confirmation email text in rails 4 , i want to send custom text for confirmation when using "confirmable"

Tags: email, ruby-on-rails-4, devise

Can anyone tell me , how can i change Confirmation email text in rails 4.
I want to send custom text for confirmation when i use "conformable" in rails with devise

Right now email sent is below

## Welcome user email here.

### You can confirm your account email through the link below:

#### Confirm my account

Thanks

Comment: did the post not help?

Answer (score 0):

It's pretty straightforward and Devise has great documentation here which you can reference if you get stuck: [Custom Mailers on Devise](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-To:-Use-custom-mailer)

Here's the summarized step-by-step:

1. Create a custom mailer class.  You will put this code in your /lib directory.  In you /lib directory, create a file called `lib/my_mailer.rb` and copy the code there.  You will then need to require this new class and you can do this at the top of initializer/devise.rb.

*lib/my_mailer.rb*

```
class MyMailer < Devise::Mailer
    helper :application # gives access to all helpers defined within `application_helper`.
    include Devise::Controllers::UrlHelpers # Optional. eg. `confirmation_url`
end
```

And then in *config/initializers/devise.rb*

```
require 'my_mailer'

Devise.setup do |config|
.
.
.
end
```

The next step is to update the devise mailer setting to point to my_mailer

*config/initializers/devise.rb*

```
config.mailer = 'MyMailer'
```

The last step is to copy the devise mailer views from the Devise gem into a new views folder directly in your app.  So inside the Devise gem you are going to go to `app/views/mailer` and copy the three files from there and paste them into a new directory in your App.  You will need to name this new directory in your app as follows `app/views/my_mailer/`

From there you can directly edit the mailers to your liking.

Hope this helps!